# C# drop downlist values not insert

Tags: c#

i have written a code to load the data to drop down list, as i written it was loaded, but while trying to insert the value of drop down list, (i mean selectedItem.text) it will not insert, instead if thtat selectedIndex=0 alone has been inserted. please correct me.

```
//Load the name to Drop down list
      public void name()
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
            ListItem i = new ListItem();
            i.Text = "-Select-";
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(i);
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Conhr.Open();
            string s;
            s = "select EmployeeName from tbl_EmploeeDetails where SiteName='" + Label5.Text + "' ";
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(s, Conhr);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ListItem m= new ListItem();
                m.Text = dr["EmployeeName"].ToString().Trim();
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(m);
            }
            dr.Close();
            Conhr.Close();
        }


//trying to insert the data for drop down list



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                        con.Open();
                        string a;
                        a = "insert into tbl_KKSUser(EName,Uname,Password)values(@en,@un,@pas)";
                        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(a, con);
                        SqlParameter paramName;
                        paramName = new SqlParameter("@en", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
                        paramName.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
                        cm.Parameters.Add(paramName);
                        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.close
         }
```

answer will be like this in data base

1   -Select-     dsad     AGEAcwBkAGY=

2   -Select-      da       AGEAZA==

Comment: Are you binding this `name()` within a `If (!IsPostBack)` clause ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta, I believe this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Every time we are working with DropDownlist the best approach is selectedvalue,
Try to use:
Set the DataSource to the reader and execute DataBind()

```
  conn.Open();   
  SqlDataReader MyDataSet = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
  ddlClassList.DataSource = MyDataSet;
  ddlClassList.DataTextField = "Field1";
  ddlClassList.DataValueField = "Field2";
  ddlClassList.DataBind();
  MyDataSet.Close();
  conn.Close();
```